# Why does my python script fail during a cronjob but works when manually ran?

Tags: python, api, http, python-requests, cron

I'm running a python script that utilizes multiple HTTP GET & POST requests. The first two succeed with no problems, but when I attempt to run the third one through the cronjob I get a *HTTP 400 53* error.
This is the output my urllib3 log gives me:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.deepai.org:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://api.deepai.org:443 "POST /api/deepdream HTTP/1.1" 400 53
```

But when I manually run the script, I get a *HTTP 200 None*.

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.deepai.org:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.deepai.org:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://api.deepai.org:443 "POST /api/deepdream HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

This is the code my script is running, using the requests python library:

```py
t2iRes = requests.post(
    "https://api.deepai.org/api/text2img",
    data={
        'text': open(filename, 'rb'),
    },
    headers={'api-key': str(APIKey)}
)
```

Cron Job:

```
58 20 * * 2 python3 path/to/file/Python-Script.py
```

If you need any more information about what I'm running or how I'm executing this, please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: "The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error". Make sure the file you want to upload is accessible. Try logging the absolute path of the file you `open` and check if that really exists

Comment: I'll try and pass a string variable instead of opening from file just to see if that works. Thanks!

Comment: For anybody else looking over, passing it with a string worked. It might have had problem grabbing the file since the path could be different when ran via cron instead of locally. Thank you!